# Plot "jump" equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I would like to verify the solution of a scalar [Hilbert-Riemann problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hilbert_problem). Roughly, the equation describes the 'jump' of the sought function along the real axis. The problem reads
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\Phi(z+i\epsilon)=G(z)\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\Phi(z-i\epsilon) \,,$$
for some 'regular' function $G(z)$.

Assuming that I have found some solution $\Phi(z)$ to the problem, how can I check using Mathematica that

$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\Phi(z+i\epsilon)-G(z)\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\Phi(z-i\epsilon)=0 \,?$$

Simply using the code

```
Plot[Limit[Phi[u + I ϵ] - G[u]Phi[u - I ϵ], ϵ -> 0], {u, -2, 2}]
```

doesn't seem to work. Can I rely on the Limit-function to take such a complex limit?

Comment: Sure, assuming `Phi` has been defined to be a function `Limit[]` can find the limit of.  I wouldn't do it inside `Plot`, probably, since `Plot` substituted approximate floating-point numbers and that might make Limit's work more difficult or unreliable.

Comment: perhaps this is what you are looking for: Table[Plot[Phi[u + I ϵ] - G[u]Phi[u - I ϵ], {u, -2, 2}],{ϵ,.1,0,-.01}]?